# Удаление открытого файла

Tags: unix, файлы, linux

Кто-нибудь может знает, возможно ли удалить файл, в который идёт поток информации, т.е. файл открыт на запись другим преложением, а мне в какой-то определённый момент времени нужно его обнулить в Unix/Linux.

провобoвал
echo > file
echo -n > file
head -c 0 > file
cat /dev/null > file

раземр не сбрасывается!

Comment: Да, конечно не сбрасывается. По причинам как раз и описанным мною ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если файл не залочен (обычно это не делается), то его можно легко удалить. Однако, исчезновение файла из дерева файлов не будет означать его фактическое удаление. На самом деле, файл будет существовать до тех пор, пока приложение, выполняющее в него запись, не закроет его. В то же время, файл будет уже нельзя открыть. В таком промежуточном состоянии он будте продолжать занимать место на диске. 
Я не уверен, что это поведение воспроизводится на всех файловых системах, но под ext3 я точно наблюдал подобное.

PS: таким образом, ответ на ваш вопрос: всё-таки это плохая идея и стоит воздержаться от этого. Тем более, что это точно будет непереносимо на другие платформы (такие как Windows).

UPD: ответ для rtfm

lsof на вход принимает имя файла, а раз файл удалён, то и файла нет. Следовательно, lsof скажет, что файл не найден. Но на самом деле, тело файла всё ещё существует, хотя ссылок на него из дерева файлов уже нет.

Проверяем догадку:

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~ $ cat - > ~/delete &
[1] 22129
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~ $ 
[1]  + suspended (tty input)  cat - > ~/delete
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~ $ /usr/sbin/lsof ~/delete
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
cat     21808 cy6ergn0m    1w   REG    8,7        0 19128453 /home/cy6ergn0m/delete
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~ $ rm -f ~/delete
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~ $ /usr/sbin/lsof ~/delete
lsof: status error on /home/cy6ergn0m/delete: No such file or directory
lsof 4.83
latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[gG]]
[-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

Comment: плевать! мненужно просто его обнулить!  просто дело втом что тутад пишется видео поток, мне нужно просто скинуть его размер!

Comment: Тогда надо понимать, что: а) видеопоток будет продолжать писаться в старый, уже "невидимый" файл; б) новый файл на месте старого создать будет можно, но они оба будут занимать место на диске. Таким образом, достичь успеха возможно лишь частично. Например, непонятно, каким образом вы продолжите запись видео в новый файл, если уже есть процесс, который пишет в старый.. тогда вам придётся его всё равно убить и запустить новый.

Comment: Так вот в этом то и дело, надо не удалять файл а обнулить! То, что он будет писаться туда это ясно! А вот как сделать так чтобы он просто скинул размер!

Comment: Нельзя сделать это снаружи. Надо заставить само приложение делать это. Это как с ротацией логов. Вы не можете просто взять и подменить лог-файл у приложения. Надо чтобы логгер самого приложения всё это делал.

Comment: Не поню уже деталей, но, кажется, просто файл удаляется, а нода остаётся и ассоциация ноды с процессом где-то фигурирует.

Comment: а что говорит lsof по поводу открытого файла?

Comment: см. UPD к моему ответу

Comment: насчёт lsof у меня был вопрос к автору :)

Answer (score 2):

Если приложение открывает файл с именем File на запись с O_APPEND, то > File в sh будет урезать файл (ls -l покажет это).

В противном случае размер, показываемый ls -l не уменьшится. Однако, если размер файла (в момент > ) превышает размер блока файловой системы (обычно 4 или 8 Kbyte), то du File покажет уменьшение файла.

Дело в следующем: Когда мы открываем файл с файловым дескриптором связана позиция в файле с которой проводится запись. Она (позиция) растет при каждом write(). Эти данные принадлежат процессу, открывшему файл. Когда другой процесс делает truncate(), размер файла в файловой системе безусловно уменьшается (и незанятые теперь блоки данных удаляются (точнее переходят в список свободных)). Однако это не затрагивает позицию записи в первом процессе (кстати, даже если сделать truncate в нем самом), поэтому при следующем write() из первого процесса длина файла возрастет. Если в этот момент прочесть файл (например cat File >fff из другого окошка), то в нем (от начала до последнего write()) будут двоичные нули.

Открытие файла с O_APPEND модифицирует поведение - при каждом write() позиция записи смещается в конец файла в соответствии с его текущим размером в файловой системе.

Надеюсь это справедливо для большинства Unix/Linux. В эмуляторах не проверял.

Comment: АДМИНУ:
Совершенно запутался с какими данными с какого компа входить.
Вышлите мне (avp), пожалуйста толковую инструкцию на
avp210159@mail.ru
Если я забыл пароль, то как его возобновить?

Answer (score 1):

Дарю бесплатную идею:

Создаёте на диске именованный канал (named pipe) (`mkfifo`). Одним концом канала тыкаете в программу, которая хочет писать видео поток. На другой конец вешаете свою программу (а, наверняка, есть и готовое решение), которая откроет реальный файл и тупо весь поток из канала будет писать в него, а по какому-нибудь сигналу (ну типа SIGHUP, как принято) переоткрывать файл.

Comment: А чем это отличается от записи в /dev/null ?

Comment: @alexlz Прошу прощения, ээээ… ну… я не понял, о чём Вы :(

Comment: Он предлагает, чтобы приложение писало не в настоящий файл, а через специальный канал-переходник. Это сработает, если данные действительно 100% потоковые и если сама программа не закочевряжится ещё по какой-то причине. Тогда этот канал можно будет перенаправлять в разные файлы или в определённый момент делать сброс.

Comment: Насчёт предложения понятно. Не понятно, чем это отличается от записи "в никуда". Разве что тем, что хвост ещё можно прочитать. Но это вопрос к автору первоначального вопроса.

Comment: @alexlz чё-то, по-моему, всё-таки, что-то не понятно… Вы вообще улавливаете, в чём проблема, поднятая в вопросе?

Comment: Не совсем. Эти данные нужны или нет?
Если нужны, и если truncate возможен, то остаток можно использовать или нет (проблемы целостности данных). 2all. Поскольку вопрос мне не ясен, и ответа у меня нет - больше я на него не отвечаю ни буквы.

Comment: Да нужны — не нужны данные — какая разница?? При чём тут долбаный /dev/null я никак не могу понять?!? «Поскольку вопрос мне не ясен» — вот с этого и надо было начинать.

Answer (score 0):

А **>your_file** в bash'е не помогает?
Вообще стандартный когда-то вопрос для начинающих юниксоидов "Как чистить логи?"
То есть любой truncate.

А удалить файл в unix-like'ах пользователь не может, он может только удалить inode этого файла в диска (операция unlink). При открытии файла inode создаётся в ядре и существует до закрытия. Удаляет файлы система при условии, что на файл не ссылается ни одна inode (ни с диска, ни из таблиц ядра)

Comment: Нет. Всё наоборот. inode - это и есть тело файла. И на него ссылаются. Это inode имеет счётчик использований и ссылаются на него элементы дерева файлов. unlink разрушает связь между деревом файловой системы и inode, и когда счётчик сходит на нуль - тело удаляется тоже. Однако, в целом верна - старый процесс будет работать со старым телом даже если вы "удалите" файл. Если создадите новый, то появится новый inode (новое тело файла) и новая связь.

Comment: А >your_file   В вопросе ведь написано, что это не помогло. Хотя, на самом деле, это иногда может помочь. Вот, например, если это cat пишет в файл, то вы можете другим cat'ом уменьшить. Но это не со всеми приложениями срабатывает. Думаю, это связано с режимами записи: потоковый append или произвольный доступ edit+append.

Comment: Позор мне. Видимо тогда ещё не проснулся.

Comment: Директории, по секрету, тоже соответствует дисковый inode, и unlink только удаляет оттуда запись о файле, поэтому он становится недоступным для доступа по имени. При открытии файла ссылка на него сохраняется в fdtable процесса до тех пор, пока открыт соответствующий дескриптор, то есть, процесс жив и сам не закрывает файл. Физически дисковые блоки освобождаются после закрытия всех дескрипторов, ссылающихся на файл, весьма асинхронно в зависимости от файловой системы, и обычно truncate() этому способствует.

Comment: Всё это действительно странно, потому что truncate() изменяет размер файлов даже при наличии обычных (не mandatory) lock'ов.