# файл удален, но функция записи проходит успешно

Tags: node.js, fs

```
let fs = require("fs");
let x = fs.openSync("123", "w+");

setInterval(()=>{
    fs.write(x, "mytext", function(){console.log(arguments)});
    }, 1000);
```

Создаю файл и записываю в него текст кодом выше. Если удалить файл, во время выполнения программы, то новый файл не будет создаваться и записываться по-факту ничего не будет, но `fs.write` все равно возвращает количество записанных байт и пустой объект ошибки.

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Каким образом
   добиться возврата ошибки при отсутствии фактической записи в файл?
   (помимо чтения его после вызова записи)
3. Каким образом открыть файл и запретить его удаление и запись до
   закрытия дескриптора в скрипте?

Comment: Это таки вроде норма, фактически файл будет удален только после ````fs.close````( если предварительно был ````rm```` или ````unlink````), пока дескриптор не закрыт, файл будет существовать и его технически можно будет "привязать" по другому пути. Механика схожа с garbage collection.

Comment: @lijil какая к черту норма, я удалил файл через проводник, при блокировке нормальной, пока дескриптор открыт я ошибку бы получал при удалении, а при таком нодовском коде я вообще все что угодно могу делать с файлом, но ноде "кажется", что он существует

Comment: @lijil если при работающем скрипте переименовать файл, то будет писать в файл с новым именем, если же файл удалить через **del /f 123**, то неизвестно куда оно пишет, но ошибок нет.

Comment: это норма для linux, node старается минимизировать различия в ос, поэтому поведение может быть и необычным для windows, вцелом мне недостает опыта в этой теме что-бы дать развернутый ответ, просто поделился тем что знаю.

Comment: например если повесить ````fs.watch```` и вызвать ````rm```` в linux выйдет "rename" событие, хотя казалось бы мы файл удалили =), можно рассматривать путь к файлу и дескриптор как ссылки, и пока хоть одна ссылка существует будет существовать и файл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Удаление открытого файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2586/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: А если вместо `"w+"` написать `"w"`?